# Nuget prompting credentials

Tags: visual-studio-2019, nuget-package, nuget-package-restore

I am using Visual Studio 2019. While building a solution its asking for credentials and build is getting failed. api.nuget.org asking username and password. 
Note: I am using public default nuget package

[image]

Comment: Please provide the error image and some brief information regards that.

Comment: @LinuXMan PFA screenshot

Comment: IS really annoying

Comment: how did you solve it?

Answer (score 2):

From the official [thread of Visual Studio's developer community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/266055/nuget-keeps-prompting-for-credentials-when-connect.html), you should consider signing out from all accounts (located on the top-right corner of Visual Studio). This should solve your issue.

After clicking on your profile, go to `Account settings...` and you'll be prompted this:

[image: Removing account from VS]

Simply remove all the accounts & enjoy!

> Note that this problem has a good chance to be related wtih NuGet packages installation permission.

Comment: i have removed the account. but still asking the same. I have signed in with one account for which the trial version is expired. Then, have applied product key. Just wondering if it could be because of that?

Comment: Are you running your account as Administrator in Windows? It is either Microsoft account problem or system account permission related error.

Comment: Yes, I'm running as administrator

Answer (score 2):

ZScalar is installed in my system. This was blocking the nuget uri. Hence, the nuget was prompting for credentials. If i use proxy, it didn't prompt for credentials.

Answer (score 0):

The answer here, for me, was the blocking of downloadable executable files by group policy.

`.nupkg` was classified as executable or just not whitelisted - so a group policy (company enforced internet setting) is what was causing the 403 error (on the command line) and this password prompt to `nuget.api.org`

The password prompt doesn't really make any sense, in my context, but I suppose if I was a network admin and I entered my network password, it might have worked.